# Reading would overrun buffer error

Tags: c#, filestream, buffer-overrun

I dont know what I'm doing wrong here. my code works as expected on the first pass but on the second pass it wont run and throws an exception that just says "Reading would overrun buffer%"

I gather I'm doing something wrong with buffer and it doesn't like me overwriting it?

I had essentially the same code and changed it to match the msdn example but no joy..

```
using (Stream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    int bytesRead = 0;
    long bytesToRead = stream.Length;

    while (bytesToRead > 0)
    {               
        int n = stream.Read (buffer, bytesRead, 1024);
        if (n == 0) break;

        //do work on buffer...

        bytesRead += n;
        bytesToRead -= n;
    }
}
```

Working in .Net 2.0 Mono.

Comment: The bytesRead variable should stay at zero, I think. It's an offset into the buffer - not the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Stream.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - second parameter is offset in the buffer and should be 0 in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Read parameters is for buffer informations, you stock the data in buffer from offset to offset+nLength
To advance in your file set
stream.Position = bytesRead;